# C++: comparing operand types of the same type

Tags: c++, types, operators

I have only been using C++ for about a week teaching myself. I tried searching for a similar question but I couldn't find one. However, this could be due to not knowing the appropriate search terms to use for my problem.

I have defined the following structure:

```
struct Sales_data {                                                             
  // empty bracket initializes to empty string                                  
  std:: string bookNo{};                                                        
  unsigned units_sold = 0;                                                      
  double revenue = 0.0;                                                         
};
```

In my `int main() {}`, I using a `if` loop to check if `book` is nonempty where `Sales_data books;` has been declared earlier. That is, I have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Sales_data {                                                             
  // empty bracket initializes to empty string                                  
  std:: string bookNo{};                                                        
  unsigned units_sold = 0;                                                      
  double revenue = 0.0;                                                         
};

int main(){
  Sales_data books;
  double price = 0.0;
  // some ostream code here
  for (int i = 0; i >= 0; ++i) {                                                
    // The for loop keeps track and counts the books                            
    while (std::cin >> books.bookNo >> books.units_sold >> price) {             
      /*                                                                        
       * while loop to allow the user to input as many books as they would      
       * like                                                                   
       */                                                                       
      if (books != Sales_data()) {                                              
        // if books is not empty print which number book for i                  
        i += 1;                                                                 
        std::cout << "Book " << i << " is " << books << std::endl;              
      }                                                                         
    }                                                                           
  }            
  return 0;
}
```

> The problem is at `if (books != Sales_data()) ...` which is where the error is

```
error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are
‘Sales_data’ and ‘Sales_data’)
       if (books != Sales_data()) {
```

It says the operand types have the same type so I don't quite get what the problem is.

Comment: ` // empty bracket initializes to empty string ` is incorrect. Do not need them

Comment: @EdHeal so just leave it blank?

Comment: `std:: string bookNo` will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement `operator!=` for your struct.

```
struct Sales_data
{
   ...

  bool operator!=(const Sales_data& other)
  {
     // Logic to determine if sales data are not equal
     return ...;
  }
}; // end definition of struct Sales_data
```

or this can be implemented as a freestanding operator

```
bool operator!=(const Sales_data& data1, const Sales_data& data2)
{
   // Logic to determine if the two instances are not equal
   return ...;
}
```

Comment: Prefer a freestanding operator, if possible.

Comment: @dustin bool is the return value of the operator function. You should try looking up a tutorial for C++ syntax. Edit: ah, misread your question. In the second option, operator!= is a function declared outside of a class or a struct, the same way that main is.

Comment: @dustin The second option is a freestanding function, declared outside of main and the struct.

Comment: @dustin You need to write logic that compares the individual fields in both structs and converts that to a boolean that represents if they're equal or not.

ex, `return data1.units_sold != data2.units_sold && data1.revenue != data2.revenue && // any other comparisons necessary`

Comment: Thanks. I was able to figure that prior to your comment. Do you know anything about: `cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka
std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
         std::cout << books << std::endl;` I read the numerous post on SO about this but I don't understand how to quell it.

Comment: You may need to overload `operator<<` for your struct.

Comment: @cocarin unfortunately, I have no idea what that means. I am only in week 2 of using C++, self teaching.

Comment: [This](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/) should help.